# Parse at ":" - Not even sure how to ask.. so here is an EX

Tags: c#, parsing, richtextbox

I have this code that I would like to parse by ":" it's hard to explain so hard to search so decided to ask my first question here

```
if (command == "hi")
{
    MessageBox.Show(command);
    skype.SendMessage(msg.Sender.Handle, nick + " Says: " + "what");
}
else { }
if (command == "what's up?")
{
    MessageBox.Show(command);
    skype.SendMessage(msg.Sender.Handle, nick + " Says: " + "nothing much");
}
else { }
```

Now what I want with the above is to have a richtextbox sort one line at a time so for EX:

```
hi:what  
what's up?:nothing much
```

And is it possible every line that is made it ad's a new if statement rather then limiting users to a certain amount?

Edit: I need it to work like this-
Message | Response
 hello:what's up?

The way the current code works is:

```
//if message "hi" 
    if (command == "hi")
    {
        //return this message if message "hi"
        skype.SendMessage(msg.Sender.Handle, nick + " Says: " + "what");
    }
```

Instead I would like a richtextbox to parse it at ":"
and make each line a new if statement.

thank you!

Comment: This is a very poorly expressed question.  Think you can take a couple minutes to sort out exactly what you want?

Comment: @Boo I've read it a couple of times. I'm confused

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are asking. You want the user to enter a multi-line text in a text box, each line in the form `question:answer`, and then the code should read these lines and for each of them execute an `if` statement like those in your example?

Answer (score 4):

I'm really not certain what you're asking for, but my assumption is that you want to get a command and know how to respond to that command.

A straightforward way to do that is with a `Dictionary<string, string>`.

```
Dictionary<string, string> commandsAndResponses = new Dictionary<string, string>();
commandsAndResponses.Add("hi", "what");
// Add the rest

if (commandsAndResponses.ContainsKey(command))
{
    MessageBox.Show(command);
    skype.SendMessage(msg.Sender.Handle, nick + " Says: " +  commandsAndResponses[command]);
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you are getting your commands and responses from a RichTextBox as a ":" separated list of strings, you can use `string.Split()` to build your dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear to me what you're asking, but if I understand you correctly, you have a string that looks like `"command:some other stuff"` and you want to separate the two parts.  If my understanding is correct, it's very easy:

```
var originalString = "command:some other stuff";
var parts = originalString.Split(new[] {':'});
var command = parts[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you really want if statements. You could do something like this:

```
string[] lines = richTextBox1.Text.Split('\n'); // split on line
foreach(string ln in lines)
{
    string[] commands = ln.Split(':');
    if(commands.Length == 2) 
    {
        // first statement 
        skype.SendMessage(msg.Sender.Handle, string.Format("{0} Says: {1}",nick, command[0]); 
        // second statement
        skype.SendMessage(msg.Sender.Handle, string.Format("{0} Says: {1}",nick, command[1]);
    }
}
```

This will loop over each line in the textbox and then work on both parts of the command, if it is there is only one ":". I will leave it up to you whether or not you allow users to use ":" in text.

Comment: Little buggy, I think I know why.. because I don't have a lot of room to post here is a pastebin link of my comment

http://pastebin.com/a8pFMexc

Comment: @TomDoobies what is causing you problems specifically? I don't see any indication of where you are having problems on the pastebin

Comment: Look it needs to do this:

message | respond
  Hello:Hey man

it just send's both the messages one at a time when no matter whats said.

Comment: @TomDoobies You can combine this method with [Eric J.'s response](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10019405/509746) which will give you what you want. Also, I didn't write logic for you, I just wrote what will give you the results. If you have separate requirements then you will have to modify the sample to meet them.

Comment: If you have Skype that would be fantastic.

Comment: @TomDoobies I do not have skype